# Redirect from/to specific URL desktop to mobile

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with this redirect for a while. I was able to get the script for mobile redirect to work. The script will recognize the mobile device and based on that redirect to either store or application (if installed).

Right now I need something more advanced. I need to redirect users to specific InApp URL (something like appname//mylink/#id123)

So, let's say user tried to open the following link on desktop:

www.mysite.com/mylink#id123
That would go to
appname//mylink/#id123

Or store if application is not installed. I need to be able to define different cases though.

Anyone saw something similar around the web? I wasn't able to figure it out and below is the script I use for basic redirect.

```
<script>
/*$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('Redirect to APP');
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

      // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"
    if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
        //return "Windows Phone";
        console.log('Windows Phone');
    }

    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        //return "Android";
        console.log('Android');
        var now = new Date().valueOf();
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (new Date().valueOf() - now > 100) return;
            window.location = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/";
        }, 25);
        window.location = "appname://";
    }


    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        //return "iOS";
        console.log('iOS');
        var now = new Date().valueOf();
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (new Date().valueOf() - now > 100) return;
            window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/appdir";
        }, 25);
        window.location = "appname://";
    }
});*/
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you mean URI intsead?

Comment: Yes! Sry for confusion :)

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. I think you can't know with JS if an app is installed or not. The best you can do is ask the user about it. ```setTimeout``` works, but if the user returns to the browser, it will get redirected to the store... :/

Comment: Really? The script I am using already does recognize the app itself?

Comment: Yes, it tries to open the app and then opens the store. But there's no way of knowing if the app is installed...

Comment: @D.Pardal that makes sense, but can it try to open the appname:// first? from URI ?

Comment: Yes. But then you'll never know if it has in fact opened. D:

Comment: @D.Pardal I understand but that's the least I can do, I believe :) Anyway you know how to do it though? Ty!